# How to access list of a class which is under a wrapper class from main controller in salesforce apex

Tags: json, class, salesforce, wrapper, apex

```
public class DemoWrapper{

   public class SomeActivity{
        public List<ABC> abcClass{get;set;}
   }


   public class ABC {
        public String subject{get;set;} 
        public String status{get;set;}  
        public String callDate{get;set;}
    }

}
```

How to assign value of class ABC in abcClass List from Main controller?? Please add some comments

Answer (score 0):

```
DemoWrapper demo = new DemoWrapper();

demo.SomeActivity = new List<demo.ABC>();
demo.ABC = abc = new Demo.ABC();
abc.Subject = 'some subject';
abc.status = 'Some status';
abc.CallDate = 'Some date string';
demo.SomeActivity.add(abc);

system.assertEquals(1, demo.SomActivity.size());
```